# Setting non-constant value on a subset of rows and columns in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, in-place, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

Let's assume I have a dataframe D:

```
D = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [3,3,4], 'c': [2, 4, 0], 'd': [-1,-1,-1]})
D

    a   b   c   d
0   1   3   2   -1
1   2   3   4   -1
2   3   4   0   -1
```

I want to sort the values in columns a, b, c in, say, first two rows, so the expected result would be

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   2   3   -1
1   2   3   4   -1
2   3   4   0   -1
```

To avoid chained assignment warning I try to do it with df.loc:

```
D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']].agg(['min', 'median', 'max'], axis=1)

    min median  max
0   1.0 2.0 3.0
1   2.0 3.0 4.0
```

```
D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']] = D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']].agg(['min', 'median', 'max'], axis=1)
D

    a   b   c   d
0   NaN NaN NaN -1
1   NaN NaN NaN -1
2   3.0 4.0 0.0 -1
```

For some reason the values don't set. I thought that it could because of different column names but
`D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']] = D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']].agg(['min', 'median', 'max'], axis=1).rename(columns={"min": "a", "median": "b", "max": "c"})`
and
`D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']] = D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']].agg(['min', 'median', 'max'], axis=1).to_numpy()`
didn't work too. Changing the values manually isn't an option because in the real example I have about 800k rows instead of 3 and want to keep the operation vectorised. So what should the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']] = np.sort(D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']], axis=1)
print (D)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3 -1
1  2  3  4 -1
2  3  4  0 -1
```

If need assign aggregate function convert ouput to numpy array by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']] = D.loc[[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']].agg(['min', 'median', 'max'], axis=1).to_numpy()
print (D)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3 -1
1  2  3  4 -1
2  3  4  0 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix you your example, use explicit conversion [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
D.loc[0:1, cols] = D.loc[0:1, cols].agg(['min', 'median', 'max'], axis=1).to_numpy()
```

If you want to sort, use [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) that will convert to array:

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
D.loc[0:1, cols] = np.sort(D.loc[0:1, cols], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3 -1
1  2  3  4 -1
2  3  4  0 -1
```